# QGIS Server on a Windows machine -where do the qgs files go?

Tags: qgis-server

I think I have installed QGIS Server correctly - I get

[image]

[image]
I have followed the process in https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows

I have entered the service capabilities under Project-->Properties-->QGIS Server and used Test Configuration with no problems but where do I put the project and data in so that I can see it as a WMS layer? It seems like section 2.3 is for Linux and not Windows systems.

**UPDATE 1**

When I try http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\MGM\MapData\animals.qgs&

I get
[image]

In httpd.conf I have
[image]

Is there anything else to do?

**UPDATE 2**

On trying the edits as per the answer for Apache

My XAMPP
[image]

My httpd_qgis-ltr.conf

```
# Parse our QGIS Apache conf files
Include C:/OSGeo4W64/httpd.d/httpd_*.conf

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_PREFIX "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_BINARIES "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/bin"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_PLUGINS "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/plugins"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_LIBRARIES "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/lib"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/translations"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_HEADERS "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/include"
DefaultInitEnv O4W_QT_DOC "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/doc"

DefaultInitEnv PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\@grasspath@\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\@grasspath@\lib;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
DefaultInitEnv QGIS_PREFIX_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr"
DefaultInitEnv QT_PLUGIN_PATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qt5\plugins"
DefaultInitEnv TEMP "C:\Users\MANGOA~1\AppData\Local\Temp"
DefaultInitEnv PYTHONHOME "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37"
DefaultInitEnv PYTHONPATH "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts"

Alias /qgis-ltr/ C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/

<Directory "C:\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    Options ExecCGI
    # Order/Allow is for Apache 2.2
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
    # Require is for Apache 2.4
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The fcgi is correct
[image]

Comment: I would expect, some response like that from a request in a browser like `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\MGM\MapData\animals.qgs&`  to see the GetCapabilities response you'd need: `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\MGM\MapData\animals.qgs&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&`

Comment: If you've set the environment correctly (and restarted Apache), then you'd just use your original request, like: `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&`

Comment: @nmtoken with `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\MGM\MapData\animals.qgs&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&` I get `<ServerException>Project file error. For OWS services: please provide a SERVICE and a MAP parameter pointing to a valid QGIS project file</ServerException>`

Comment: Parameter names should be case insensitive, but you could try SERVICE and MAP, rather than my service and map

Comment: @nmtoken Still get the same issue - can you add some examples from your system? and how the qgs project you load looks? this will allow me to check if I have done things correctly.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck now as to how to help with your config, I don't use XAMPP which is the simple example used in the documentation.  I updated the answer to show which Apache config file I would have edited based on your config. My config works though it will take you away from the documented example.  In essence the  .qgs file can go anywhere.  The web server needs to be able to see the qgis configuration, the qgis server needs to be able to find the project file.

Comment: I `added some information to the QGIS server fields in the layer properties and also to the metadata properties`  Did you do this for your project?  Just wondering whether this step is required before it will recognise the project as serve-able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MapServer (which also uses a map parameter to point at the configuration), the location of the map file(s) read .qgs files here is not important.  You just need a location that is readable by the server, so instead of `/home/qgis/projects/world.qgs` you could have your qgs file(s) at `c:\WxS\qgisserver\projects\project1\` and the service endpoint would be

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=c:\WxS\qgisserver\projects\project1\world.qgs&
```

But if you want you can use the Apache server configuration to hide the `map` location.

For MapServer you'd use:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" MS_MAPFILE=C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/world.qgs
```

Looking at section 2.3 I assume that instead of `MS_MAPFILE` you need to use `PROJECT_FILE` like:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" PROJECT_FILE=C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/world.qgs
```

If you plan to have multiple WMS (other OWS services) on the same server, just add a project sub-folder in the cgi-bin.

So the service URL becomes:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/project1/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=c:\WxS\qgisserver\projects\project1\world.qgs&
```

and the Apache config:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cgi-bin/project1/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" PROJECT_FILE=C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/world.qgs
```

In the Apache config file you need to ensure that `LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so` is enabled, and can add the SetEnvIf in the conf file; alternatively you can add the SetEnvIf to its own httpd config file and then point the Apache config to that location.

So you could have:

```
# Parse our QGISServer Apache conf files
Include C:/WxS/qgisserver/httpd.d/httpd_*.conf
```

Then have a file called `httpd_Project1.conf` and in that file you might have:

```
Alias /Project1/ "C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/www/"
<Directory "C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/www/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    Require all granted
</Directory>

SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cgi-bin/project1/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe" PROJECT_FILE=C:/WxS/qgisserver/projects/project1/world.qgs
```

*The Alias here allows you to create a set of web pages to accompany your service*

That's how it works with MapServer and Apache on Windows.

**QGIS is essentially the same**

Installing from `osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe`, and selecting the `qgis-ltr-server` (and dependencies) on a PC that already has Apache (with fcgi), and MapServer, and QGIS installed from other routes...

For example I don't use XAMPP, but use Apache HTTP binaries form [ApacheLounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/).

Installing to `C:\apps\OSGeo4W64`

In that folder we have `C:\apps\OSGeo4W64\httpd.d` and a file `httpd_qgis-ltr.conf` that gives web server settings.

To get the installed version of Apache to see this configuration, I added

```
# Parse our QGIS Apache conf files
Include C:/apps/OSGeo4W64/httpd.d/httpd_*.conf
```

To the Apache httpd.conf file, which on your system I think is at:

```
c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

and restarted Apache; I used the wildcard to allow the option of adding other configuration files in that location.

In the `httpd_qgis-ltr.conf` file we have a line `Alias /qgis-ltr/ C:\apps\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/` where `C:\apps\OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/` is the folder with the server executable `qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe`

So now we can use:

```
http://localhost/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?
```

To get an error warning, that shows us the server is working.

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0">
    <ServiceException code="Service configuration error">
    Service unknown or unsupported</ServiceException>
```

If we add the `service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&` parameters we get an empty response like in your first screenshot.

```
http://localhost/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&
```

I then created a QGIS project `surfaceGeology.qgs` and saved it at: `C:\WxS\qs\apps\test\1ge` I added some information to the QGIS server fields in the layer properties and also to the metadata properties.

[image: QGIS project with metadata]

If add the map parameter to the request, I now get a service response for my surfaceGeology project.

```
http://localhost/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&map=c:/WxS/qs/apps/test/1ge/surfaceGeology.qgs
```

The direction of the slashes in the path isn't important (you can use `C:\WxS\qs\apps\test\1ge\`).

To get QGIS to use the service give the endpoint:

```
http://localhost/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=c:/WxS/qs/apps/test/1ge/surfaceGeology.qgs
```

[image: QGIS service added to QGIS desktop]

[image: QGIS service, showing legend (WMS GetLegendGraphic) and information (WMS GetFeatureInfo)]

Comment: I have tried the above but am getting an issue -please see updated question.

Comment: You need to add, service, request, and optionally version parameters to the end point

Comment: Can you send me a working example from your system so I can follow the same?

Comment: I just tried this with no luck - the only difference is my Apache is on 8080. I get Not Found error when I try - http://localhost:8080/qgis-ltr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe? -will update the question with screen grabs now.

Comment: Thanks - I tried to add `Include C:/OSGeo4W64/httpd.d/httpd_*.conf` to the httpd.conf in `C:\xampp\apache\conf` but then Apache doesn't start. Should I move the dll files in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\server` to the `C:\xampp\apache` folder? When installing QGIS Server from `osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe` it didn't show anything on where to install it. I have no issue with using Mapserver if this is easier, I was just trying to follow the process in `https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows` -Can you add some screen grabs of your system working?

Comment: At a command window `cd  c:\xampp\apache\bin` then use `httpd -t` to find the error.    By including the `httpd_qgis-ltr.conf` and by following the XAMPP notes, you have introduced a conflict.  I would leave the dlls where they are.