# Guide on configuring WFS on QGIS Server

Tags: qgis-server

I've configured a WMS service on QGIS Server by using https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/wms.html and [QGIS Server on a Windows machine -where do the qgs files go?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379191/qgis-server-on-a-windows-machine-where-do-the-qgs-files-go) but was trying to see how I can also serve WFS.

When I try 'http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe' I get
[image]
[image]

WMS works fine using `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=C:%5Cpublic_ftp%5Cftpuser%5Cd%5CMGM%5CMapData%5Canimals.qgs`

[image]

**What do I need to setup to allow it to serve WFS?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go in the menu "Project" > "Properties...", choose in the configuration the section about "QGIS Server". Then, go to section "WFS Capabilities" and tick layers you want to publish (see below screenshot)

At the moment, you did not tick any vector layers in your QGIS project, so that's why when you try to consume your WFS from localhost, you got the message "capabilities document contained no layers."

[image: Set WFS Capabilities]

**Edit due to comment:**

For enable editing (full), you need to also tick columns "Update", "Insert", "Delete" shown above in the screenshot and not only "Published" column

PS: infos from https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#wfs-capabilities

Comment: Thanks - that worked and now I am wondering if it's possible to make the WFS features editable in QGIS?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Can it also serve xyz tiles?

Comment: Yes with WMTS (section WMTS Capabilities in the screenshot) but works well only with EPSG 3857 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34826

Comment: and what would the format of the request be `https://server.com/path/{z}_{x}_{y}.png`? What do we put in the 'Advertised URL` section?

Comment: Tile pattern for WMTS is different for the xyz tiles like OpenStreetMap. You do not define it in the advertised URL

Comment: How do we define it? and what would it be?

Comment: You just tick layers you want to publish in the "WMTS capabilities" section with "Published", "PNG", "JPEG", you also choose Grids CRS using "EPSG:3857" (and you tick "Published" here also. Then, you can add the QGIS project as WMTS using URL similar to "http://localhost:8080/ows/?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=your_qgis_project.qgs" (mileage may vary due to the way you install QGIS server)