# Seeking QGIS Server WMS Examples

Tags: wms, qgis-server, service-recommendations

I am working to install a QGIS Server WMS via Apache and am curious if there are any existing QGIS Server WMS sites out there that I can try. I've been looking and can find plenty of WMS sites out there, but none that I can be sure are using QGIS Server. I don't care what the data is, i just want to see a working service.

Comment: If it's an open data service that you seek then I think the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be the place to ask.

Comment: I'm not looking for data. I am looking for examples of WMS sites created using QGIS Server. Thanks.

Comment: Every WMS server implements the same WMS standard. Why it feels important to know that some service is made just with QGIS server? Usually service admins are doing their best for hiding the make and model.

Comment: @JerryH. you can try the free tier of Qgis Cloud: https://qgiscloud.com/

Comment: Out of interest what do you hope to gain by seeing a QGIS example WMS vs a non-QGIS example WMS?

Comment: Looking at the sextant example in the answer, the server admin has hidden the location of the project file; to understand how to do this take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379191/qgis-server-on-a-windows-machine-where-do-the-qgs-files-go

Answer (score 1):

GeoSeer https://www.geoseer.net/rl.php?ql=2b7bccfc417657bf&p=1&q=QGIS%20server# finds one with search "QGIS server".

The GetCapabilities URL is https://sextant.ifremer.fr/services/wms/iga?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities.

Maybe you can find more by trying with other search terms.